# Azure DevOps-Want to export test execution results(Outcome-Pass, fail) in excel from Azure DevOps Test Plan with linked work items -UserStory/Feature)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Want to export test execution result(Outcome-Pass, fail) in **excel** from Azure DevOps Test Plan with linked work items (User story or Features).

This is specific to manually testing done in Azure Test Plan inside Dynamic test Suites.
Or Is there any API call which give me this details in simple format Test case id, title, run by, executed on, execution date, outcome, linked items.

Comment: Hi attinderdeep, what’s the latest status of your issue? Has my post helped?

Answer (score 0):

During my tests, you could refer to the rest apis below.

If you want to query the Test Point result, you could refer to [Points-list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/points/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/{planId}/Suites/{suiteId}/points?api-version=7.0`

If you want to query the specific Test Runs, you could refer to [Runs - Get Test Run By Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/get-test-run-by-id?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs/{runId}?includeDetails={includeDetails}&api-version=7.0`